# yii validation for ajax form post

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I'm trying to make an ajax calculator using Yii. i know i can use javascript, but since i'm new to Yii i would like to understand how things work.

here is my code in my view

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'loan-calculator-form', 
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false, // thisturns off AJAX validation 
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array( 
                'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                'validateOnChange'=>true, 
        ), 
)); ?>


<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'price'); ?>
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">RM</span>
                    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'price',array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'price'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'downpayment'); ?>
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">RM</span>
                    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'downpayment',array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'downpayment'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'rate'); ?>
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'rate',array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>

                    <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                </div>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'rate'); ?>
            </div>

        </div>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'yearloan'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-footer">


    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton("Calculate", 
            array('buttonType'=>'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block',
                                                                 'onclick'=>"calcLoan();"
                                                                 )
    );
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calcLoan()
        {
            <?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
                'url'=>array('/loan-calculator'),
                'data'=> "js:$(this).serialize()",
                'type'=>'post',
                'dataType'=>'json',
                'cache' => true, 
                'success'=>"function(data)
                    {
                        $('#totalLoanAmount').html(data.totalLoanAmount);
                        $('#monthlyInstallment').html(data.monthlyInstallment);
                        $('#loanCalcTable').html(data.loanCalcTable);
                    } ",
            ));
            ?>
            return false; 

        }
    </script>
```

in my model i did add the proper rules like "required"

but when i press submit on my form, the error client side error checking works. if form is valid, the form will post and the onlick will execute too. i do not want the form to post. i want to use an ajax post.

when i set `enableAjaxValidation'=>true, 'enableClientValidation'=>true, without the 'clientOptions' array` and i submit the form. the ajax post still happens when there are errors. and it returns this json

`{"CalculatorsForm_price":["Car Purchase Price cannot be blank."],"CalculatorsForm_downpayment":["Down Payment cannot be blank."],"CalculatorsForm_rate":["Interest Rate cannot be blank."]}`

is there away i do an ajax post ONLY if the form is valid?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CHtml::submitButton()` use the below code -

```
<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
    'Continue',
    CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('/loan-calculator')),
    array(
        'type'=>'post',
        'dataType'=>'json',
        'success'=>'js:function(data){
             if(data.status == "success") {
                  [.....]
             } else {
                  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                       if(document.getElementById(key+"_em_"))
                            document.getElementById(key+"_em_").innerHTML = val;
                       $("#loan-calculator-form #"+key+"_em_").show();
                  });
             }
        }'
    ),
    array(
         'name'=>'submit',
         'class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block'
    )
);
?>
```

Please make the changes accordingly.

I hope it helps.

Comment: by using `ajaxSubmitButton()` the rules in model don't work. the ajax post happens anyway

Comment: Have you tried only -
'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
'enableClientValidation'=>true,

without the 'clientOptions' array?

Comment: yup. by doing that. the ajax post still happens. but it returns the json `{"CalculatorsForm_price":["Car Purchase Price cannot be blank."],"CalculatorsForm_downpayment":["Down Payment cannot be blank."],"CalculatorsForm_rate":["Interest Rate cannot be blank."]}`

Comment: is there away to not do the ajax post if the form has errors?

Comment: 1. Posting will always happen - ajax or not. Its about displaying the errors after the post.

2. In normal post - the page reloads and displays the errors at the top of the form or next to the related element.

3. I have edited the answer for dislaying the error messages for ajax post.

Comment: Also make sure you have written - 
`$this->performAjaxValidation($model);` in the controller-action that loads this view. The `$model` could be any other name in your code.

Comment: ok now your new code works on error checking. but when i fill up the form this is posted thru ajax `CalculatorsForm[downpayme... 9
CalculatorsForm[price] 8000
CalculatorsForm[rate] 4
CalculatorsForm[yearloan] 1` but no response. which is strange.

Comment: in my controller i have this `if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
     {
      if($model->validate()) 
         { ...` it doesn't go past `$model->validate()`

Comment: Try this - `if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) { if($model->validate()) { [..form is ok..] }else{ echo CActiveForm::validate($model); Yii::app()->end(); } }`. Please mention if already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Use `afterValidate` property

```
    <?php 
    $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array
    (
        'id'=>'loan-calculator-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array
        (
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
            'afterValidate'=>'js:function(form,data,hasError)
            {
                if(!hasError)
                {
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                            "type":"POST",
                            "url":"'.CHtml::normalizeUrl(array("controller/action")).'",
                            "data":form.serialize(),
                            "success":function(data){},                                        
                     });
                 }
              }'
        ),
    )); 
    ?>

    ........
    Your form fields
    ......

    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>

   <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: this still posts the form, even on empty fields with no error messages. And when i fill up the form, it still posts too. no ajax at all